# read path param and a json body request at the same time in a method

Tags: java, json, web-services, jersey

I am getting the following error when my method looks like this

```
@POST
    @Path("/share")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response shareit(@PathParam("USERID") String userID,Map<String,String[]> paramValue){

.....
.....

}
```

It works fine if I remove either one from the parameter @PathParam("USERID") String userID  or Map paramValue. Can I not read path param and read a json body request at the same time ?

ERROR:

```
Dec 01, 2013 11:30:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /CloudServices threw load() exception
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.app.cloud.share.Share.shareit(java.lang.String,java.util.Map) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[application/json], producedTypes=[application/json], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.rjil.cloud.share.Share, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@54fe88f3]}, handlingMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.rjil.cloud.share.Share.shareit(java.lang.String,java.util.Map), parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.lang.String, source=USERID, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=interface java.util.Map, source=null, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class javax.ws.rs.core.Response}, nameBindings=[]}']
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:287)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:302)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:349)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3954)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't have `{USERID}` placeholder defined in any `@Path` annotation (it's not on your resource method and I guess it's not in `@Path` annotation on your resource class either). You need to match `@PathParam("USERID")` to a template in `@Path` usually:

```
@Path("/share/{USERID}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related with the "return type" of your API method, which you have defined as `Response`, see error message:

> No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response

You should specify your own "Response" type (which is supposed to return a JSON object). To define the "request" and "response" types you could use JAXB (https://jaxb.java.net/), which basically allows you to specify the an object that defines the "format" of the messages to be exchanged (received and sent) by the API method. This is very nice, because allows you to automate handling of JSON (but also XML) and other MIME representations.

Comment: I think you're mistaken.  You've truncated the error message above.  The full error message (with package names omitted for readability) is "No injection source found for parameter of type public Response Share.shareit(String, Map)".  It's complaining about the whole method signature, not just the return type.

I often return Response objects and it's okay as long as you put the JSON object in the response with Response.entity().